# How can I get main source file path from MatchCallback::onStartOfTranslationUnit()?

Tags: clang, libtooling

For now I can get it only in `MatchCallback::run(const MatchResult& r)`:

```
r.SourceManager.getFileEntryForID(r.SourceManager.getMainFileID())->getName().str()
```

and cache for future use. But I might need it in my MatchCallback subclass even if no matches were found in current file. It's weird that `onStartOfTranslationUnit()` does not give a clue which translation unit is started.

Answer (score 0):

### Not easily

Unfortunately, there isn't an easy way to get the main file from
the `onStartOfTranslationUnit` method of
[`MatchCallback`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ast__matchers_1_1MatchFinder_1_1MatchCallback.html).
The call site is in
[`clang/lib/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchFinder.cpp`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/release/16.x/clang/lib/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchFinder.cpp#L437):

```
    for (MatchCallback *MC : Matchers->AllCallbacks) {
      if (EnableCheckProfiling)
        Timer.setBucket(&TimeByBucket[MC->getID()]);
      MC->onStartOfTranslationUnit();        // <-----
    }
```

The caller has access to an
[`ASTContext`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ASTContext.html)
in its `ActiveASTContext` member, from which we could easily get the
main source file, but it chooses not to pass it.

### Workaround: Intercepting at a higher level

Assuming you're using `MatchCallback` in a way similar to the
[tutorials](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html),
somewhere you are making a
[`MatchFinder`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ast__matchers_1_1MatchFinder.html)
object and using `addMatcher` to arrange for it to call your callback
methods, something like:

```
  MatchFinder Finder;
  Finder.addMatcher(..., &myCallbackObject);
  return Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory(&Finder).get());
```

In this construction, `MatchFinder::newASTConsumer` will be called,
which makes an intermediate object of type `MatchASTConsumer` (which
is private to the implementation), which invokes the `MatchCallback`
methods.

To insert additional processing into this chain, we need to:

- Define `MyMatchFinder` whose `newASTConsumer` creates a
  `MyMatchASTConsumer`.
- Define `MyMatchASTConsumer` whose `HandleTranslationUnit` method
  calls `MyMatchFinder::matchAST`.
- Define `MyMatchFinder::matchAST`, which calls a new `onTU` callback
  that accepts an `ASTContext`.  This requires that `MyMatchFinder`
  carry its own pointer to the callbacks object.
- Define and use the `onTU` callback instead of the old
  `onStartOfTranslationUnit`.
- Create a `MyMatchFinder` and pass that to `Tool` instead.

### Complete example

The following files provide a complete example demonstrating the
approach.

`ast-match-finder.cc`:

```
// ast-match-finder.cc
// Demonstrate the MatchFinder::MatchCallback mechanism, and add
// ability to get the main source file upon notification of beginning
// a new translation unit.
//
// Based on:
//   * https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html
//   * https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/ASTMatchFinder_8h_source.html
//     (which has many compilation errors that needed fixing)

#include "clang/AST/Decl.h"                      // CXXRecordDecl
#include "clang/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchFinder.h"    // MatchFinder
#include "clang/Frontend/FrontendActions.h"      // newFrontendActionFactory
#include "clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h"   // CommonOptionsParser
#include "clang/Tooling/CompilationDatabase.h"   // CompilationDatabase
#include "clang/Tooling/Tooling.h"               // ClangTool

#include <memory>                                // unique_ptr
#include <string>                                // string

using clang::ast_matchers::MatchFinder;
using clang::ast_matchers::cxxRecordDecl;
using clang::ast_matchers::hasDefinition;
using clang::ast_matchers::hasName;

using clang::ASTConsumer;
using clang::ASTContext;
using clang::CXXRecordDecl;
using clang::SourceManager;

using clang::tooling::ClangTool;
using clang::tooling::CommonOptionsParser;
using clang::tooling::CompilationDatabase;
using clang::tooling::newFrontendActionFactory;

using std::make_unique;
using std::string;
using std::unique_ptr;


class HandleMatch : public MatchFinder::MatchCallback {
public:
  // This is the ordinary 'run' callback.
  virtual void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult &Result) override {
    const CXXRecordDecl *Class =
      Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<CXXRecordDecl>("id");
    llvm::outs()
      << "found it: "
      << Class->getLocation().printToString(*(Result.SourceManager))
      << "\n";
  }

  // This is the normal callback for the start of a TU, but there is no
  // way to get the main file name from here, unfortunately, which makes
  // it less useful than it could be.  I'm including it just to show
  // that it is still being called.
  virtual void onStartOfTranslationUnit() override {
    llvm::outs() << "onStartOfTranslationUnit\n";
  }

  // We define a new callback that gets the required info, and then have
  // to call it ourselves.
  void onTU(ASTContext &context) {
    SourceManager &sm = context.getSourceManager();
    llvm::outs()
      << "onTU: "
      << sm.getFileEntryForID(sm.getMainFileID())->getName()
      << "\n";
  }
};


// This class substitutes for clang::ast_matchers::MatchFinder by
// arranging to call 'onTU' at the right time.
class MyMatchFinder : public MatchFinder {
public:      // data
  HandleMatch *m_handleMatch;

public:      // methods
  explicit MyMatchFinder(HandleMatch *handleMatch)
    : m_handleMatch(handleMatch)
  {}

  // This is what 'newFrontendActionFactory' calls.  It is effectively
  // the entry point to the FE action system.
  unique_ptr<ASTConsumer> newASTConsumer();

  // This will be invoked by 'MyMatchASTConsumer'/
  void matchAST(ASTContext &context)
  {
    m_handleMatch->onTU(context);

    // This does the normal MatchFinder stuff, including calling
    // 'onStartOfTranslationUnit'.
    MatchFinder::matchAST(context);
  }
};


// This class is a substitute for the 'MatchASTConsumer' class defined
// in ASTMatchFinder.cpp, inside the implementation of 'MatchFinder'.
class MyMatchASTConsumer : public ASTConsumer {
public:      // data
  MyMatchFinder *m_myFinder;

public:      // methods
  MyMatchASTConsumer(MyMatchFinder *myFinder)
    : m_myFinder(myFinder)
  {}

private:     // methods
  // This is the ASTConsumer callback we need to override.
  void HandleTranslationUnit(ASTContext &Context) override {
    // Call MyMatchFinder::matchAST instead of MatchFinder::matchAST.
    m_myFinder->matchAST(Context);
  }
};


// This has to be defined out of line because it needs the definition
// of 'MyMatchASTConsumer'.
unique_ptr<ASTConsumer> MyMatchFinder::newASTConsumer()
{
  return make_unique<MyMatchASTConsumer>(this);
}


static llvm::cl::OptionCategory MyToolCategory("my-tool options");

int main(int argc, char const **argv)
{
  // This part is boilerplate.
  auto ExpectedParser = CommonOptionsParser::create(argc, argv, MyToolCategory);
  if (!ExpectedParser) {
    llvm::errs() << ExpectedParser.takeError();
    return 2;
  }
  CommonOptionsParser& OptionsParser = ExpectedParser.get();
  ClangTool Tool(OptionsParser.getCompilations(),
                 OptionsParser.getSourcePathList());

  // The handler for matches, augmented to received 'onTU' calls.
  HandleMatch handleMatch;

  // Use the customized 'MyMatchFinder' so we can get the 'onTU'
  // callback.
  MyMatchFinder finder(&handleMatch);

  // The rest of this is just some placeholder match expression, plus
  // more boilerplate for running the Tool.
  finder.addMatcher(cxxRecordDecl(hasName("AClass"),
                                  hasDefinition()).bind("id"),
                    &handleMatch);
  return Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory(&finder).get());
}


// EOF
```

`Makefile`:

```
# Makefile

# Default target.
all:
.PHONY: all


# ---- Configuration ----
# Installation directory from a binary distribution.
# Has five subdirectories: bin include lib libexec share.
# Downloaded from: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-14.0.0/clang+llvm-14.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz
CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR = $(HOME)/opt/clang+llvm-14.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04

# ---- llvm-config query results ----
# Program to query the various LLVM configuration options.
LLVM_CONFIG := $(CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR)/bin/llvm-config

# C++ compiler options to ensure ABI compatibility.
LLVM_CXXFLAGS := $(shell $(LLVM_CONFIG) --cxxflags)

# Directory containing the clang library files, both static and dynamic.
LLVM_LIBDIR := $(shell $(LLVM_CONFIG) --libdir)

# Other flags needed for linking, whether statically or dynamically.
LLVM_LDFLAGS_AND_SYSTEM_LIBS := $(shell $(LLVM_CONFIG) --ldflags --system-libs)


# ---- Compiler options ----
# C++ compiler.
#CXX = g++
CXX = $(CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR)/bin/clang++

# Compiler options, including preprocessor options.
CXXFLAGS =
CXXFLAGS += -Wall
CXXFLAGS += -Werror

# Silence a warning about a multi-line comment in DeclOpenMP.h.
CXXFLAGS += -Wno-comment

# Get llvm compilation flags.
CXXFLAGS += $(LLVM_CXXFLAGS)

# Tell the source code where the clang installation directory is.
CXXFLAGS += -DCLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR='"$(CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR)"'

# Linker options.
LDFLAGS =

# Pull in clang+llvm via libclang-cpp.so, which has everything, but is
# only available as a dynamic library.
LDFLAGS += -lclang-cpp

# Needed for llvm::InitLLVM, which is missing from libclang-cpp.so.
LDFLAGS += -lLLVMSupport

# Arrange for the compiled binary to search the libdir for that library.
# Otherwise, one can set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH envvar before running it.
# Note: the -rpath switch does not work on Windows.
LDFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath=$(LLVM_LIBDIR)

# Get the needed -L search path, plus things like -ldl.
LDFLAGS += $(LLVM_LDFLAGS_AND_SYSTEM_LIBS)


# ---- Recipes ----
# Compile a C++ source file.
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $<

# Executable.
all: ast-match-finder.exe
ast-match-finder.exe: ast-match-finder.o
    $(CXX) -g -Wall -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

# Quick test.
.PHONY: run
run: ast-match-finder.exe
    ./ast-match-finder.exe test.cc test2.cc --

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) *.o *.exe


# EOF
```

`test.cc`:

```
// test.cc
// Test input for ast-match-finder.exe.

class AClass {};

// EOF
```

`test2.cc`:

```
// test2.cc
// Test input for ast-match-finder.exe.



class AClass {};

// EOF
```

Example run:

```
$ make run
./ast-match-finder.exe test.cc test2.cc --
onTU: /home/scott/wrk/learn/clang/ast-match-finder/test.cc
onStartOfTranslationUnit
found it: /home/scott/wrk/learn/clang/ast-match-finder/test.cc:4:7
onTU: /home/scott/wrk/learn/clang/ast-match-finder/test2.cc
onStartOfTranslationUnit
found it: /home/scott/wrk/learn/clang/ast-match-finder/test2.cc:6:7
```

Observe that we see both TUs, each with a match on a distinct line.